# Upgrade hibernate from 3.1.3 to 4.0

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, orm

We are going to upgrade hibernate from 3.1.3 to 4.0. I found most of them are deprecated. Have changed most of the classes/interfaces.But I'm not able to replace the below .Searched in hibernate 4 API,coudn't find.

```
import org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher;
import org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager;
import org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter;


Connection conn = session.connection();
```

Can someone help me what classes/interfaces to replace in the above stmt's place ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of these do not have direct replacements, so will depend on what you are trying to accomplish.  Note too the ones moved to `spi` and `internal` packages; `spi` indicates things your application code should not be using; they are meant for integration code or Hibernate use.  `internal` is stuff not at all supported for application use; it is meant for Hibernate-only internal use.

The concept of a "batcher" has been changed up to instead model a "batch".  See `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.spi.Batch`.  Note `spi`.

ConnectionManager has no real direct replacement.

JDBCExceptionReporter, again has no real direct replacement.  Most likely you are looking for `org.hibernate.exception.spi.SQLExceptionConverter`, but again depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

`session.connection()` is replaced by `session.doWork()` using the Connection you are passed.

Some of these are covered in the migration guides.  Some are not because they are not really intended for you to use.